# Write a getCapitals function that accepts a string and returns an array of all capital letters that are in the string in the same order

Tags: javascript

```js
function getCapitals(string) {
  var newString = [''];
  for (var i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
    if (string[i] === string[i].toUpperCase()) {
      newString += string[i];
    }
  }
  return newString;
}

console.log(getCapitals("Madjbaj Avveyhe"));
```

EXPECTED: `["M", "A"]`

RESULT: `["M A"]`

Comment: Use [Array.prototype.push()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) to add elements to an array

Answer (score 0):

You can use `split` and `filter` to get the result in single line

```js
const getCapitals = (str) => str.split('').filter(c => c.trim() && c.toUpperCase() === c);

console.log(getCapitals("Madjbaj Avveyhe"));
```

You can also use regex here as:

```js
const getCapitals = (str) => str.match(/[A-Z]/g)

console.log(getCapitals("Madjbaj Avveyhe"));
```